# Fastest screen sharing between mac and windows?

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop

Now that [Skype](http://www.skype.com) 2.8 is out of beta with screen sharing, I'm interested to hear what people have tried and/or prefer for screen sharing between Windows and Mac OS X.

Options I'm aware of include:

- Skype
- [CrossLoop](http://crossloop.com)
- [Adobe ConnectNow](http://acrobat.com)

My main use for this is doing remote tech support for my extended family. I'm on a mac and most of them are on Windows. I've tried Mac to Mac using Adobe's product and [iChat](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/ichat.html) and iChat is much faster.

What do you like? What do you recommend against?

Comment: I'm going to have to try LogMeIn.

The issue I have with VNC is that it requires opening ports -- is that still true? If I'm doing tech support for various family members in different parts of the US, I can't rely on the router being properly configured.

Comment: Yes, VNC does require opening ports, unless you use it on port 80. LogMeIn is probably easiest, and the free version may work well enough for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com/). I've only used it between Windows machines, but it seems to work quite well. They have a Mac version available.

Comment: LogMeIn is really fast compared to VNC or iRAPP.

Comment: I've been using their free http://www.join.me service a lot in the past few months. It requires virtually no setup and is quite responsive.

Answer (score 2):

Just plain VNC will work between pretty much any platform, so long as you have a client and server. Mac OS X has built-in VNC capabilities accessible through the Sharing preferences, and a built-in VNC client located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.app`. For Windows, [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) is a fairly good server/client program. As JP mentioned, you can also use RDP when controlling a Windows computer, and there's an official Mac RDP client available.

Another great cross-platform product (with free and other paid versions, though for Mac only the free version exists) is [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com/). They also have an iPhone client, which is great for traveling without a laptop.

Comment: The built-in VNC capability on the mac is VNC server side. As stated in the question, I'm on a mac and need to see remote Windows screens.

Comment: No, read what I wrote: there's a client at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.app`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it's the "fastest", but I use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) for both Mac-to-Mac and Mac-to-Win screen sharing and it works well and with a little tweaking (quality all the way down), it's let me help people on extremely poor connections (say, GPRS dongles).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like doing it with [RDP](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx) if I'm going Mac to Windows.  But, also [gotomypc](https://www.gotomypc.com/en_US/entry.tmpl?Action=rgoto&_sf=2) is (surprisingly) very good too.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Timbuktu](http://www.netopia.com/software/products/tb2/mac/) for Mac-Mac and Mac-PC, and it's very fast. It doesn't feel like an OS X application though (it looks very 'classic') and it's not really cheap. It does a lot more than just screen sharing mind you!

I use RDP to get from Mac to PC frequently (I use a Mac myself and my company server is Win2k3), and as others have said, VNC works fine. There is a Mac VNC product called Chicken Of The VNC which you might find faster/leaner than the built-in one.